# Etymology of "humbug"

Tags: etymology

We were discussing humbugs in the office the other day (principally arguing over whether the ones with brown stripes were real humbugs), so I looked up the etymology and found plenty of information about the origin of the word *humbug* to mean deception or dishonesty (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbug)).

One might argue that in this context lots of explanations are the same as no explanations, but none of them mention the minty meaning. So I was wondering if anyone knew how a word that used to mean what is reported by the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=humbug) also came to mean a black-and-white striped peppermint sweet:

> 1751, student slang, "trick, jest, hoax, deception," also as a verb, of unknown origin. A vogue word of the early 1750s; its origin was a subject of much whimsical speculation even then.

Comment: http://blog.oup.com/2010/03/a-postscript-to-the-series-on-unpleasant-people-humbug/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[*The Glutton's Glossary*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=vAQOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA144&dq=humbug%20%22boiled%20sweet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=REwhT96DHuSB4gTshNmcCA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=humbug%20%22boiled%20sweet%22&f=false) by John Ayto says:

> The use of the word *humbug* for a stripy peppermint-flavoured boiled sweet seems to date from the nineteenth century: the *Oxford English Dictionary* notes it as being 'remembered in common use in Gloucestershire' in the 1820s, while Elizabeth Gaskell in *Sylvia's Lover's* (1863) explained: 'He had provided himself with a paper of humbugs for  the child — "humbugs" being the North-country term for certain lumps of toffy, well-flavoured with peppermint.'
>
> ...
>
> It originally meant 'practical joke, hoax' rather than the present, more earnest 'hypocritical sham', and its application to an article of food may be of similar inspiration to trifle.

An [1876](http://www.archive.org/details/s5notesqueries06londuoft) *Notes and Queries* (the Victorian precursor to Stack Exchange) suggests an etymology:

> The kind of sweetmeat called humbug can still
> be bought at Taunton. It is a thin, oval-shaped
> piece of toffee, with an almond in the middle, and
> is, I suspect, so called because, after sucking for a
> short time at the toffee, you suddenly find yourself
> come to an almond. H. F. BOYD.

Comment: So the sweets were humbugging their consumers! Thank you.